# State being set with delayed selected value when onChange is called

Tags: reactjs

I am running into an issue where I have a date input that is connected to a state value on each change of the input the state is being set to the previous value.

**Example**

Input value = 2020-06-01

Input change = 2020-05-25 (State = 2020-06-01)

Input change = 2020-05-27 (State = 2020-05-25)

And I'm not sure what is driving this delay in the value being set. Is it how the onChange function is being called? Am I not setting the right state value?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.setStartDate = this.setStartDate.bind(this);
        this.setEndDate = this.setEndDate.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            startDate: '',
            endDate: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            startDate: DateTime.local().minus({ days: 7 }).ts,
            endDate: dt.toMillis(new Date())
        })
    }

    setStartDate = startDate => {
        this.setState({
            startDate: startDate
        });
        console.log(this.state.startDate)
      };

    setEndDate = endDate => {
        this.setState({
            endDate: endDate
        });
    };

    render() {
        var startDate = dt.toISODate(this.state.startDate);
        var endDate = dt.toISODate(this.state.endDate);

        return (
            <DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.setStartDate} className="text-black text-center rounded-md p-2" />
            <DatePicker selected={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.setEndDate} className="text-black text-center rounded-md p-2" />
        )
    }
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: your console output shows previous state. if you want to log current state then pass callback function to setState method. ie. `this.setState({startDate: startDate }, () =>  console.log(this.state.startDate))`

Comment: react state update is async that why .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    this.setState({
        startDate: startDate
    });
    console.log(this.state.startDate)
```

in the above code setState is an asynchronus function so you wont get the updated value right away. you can try this.

```
    this.setState({
            startDate: startDate
    } , () =>  console.log(this.state.startDate));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but if I `console.log(startDate)` in the `render()` section it still reflects the original state value that is set at `componentDidMount()`. Is there something wrong with my onChange functions or the `selected` attribute found in my input tags?

Comment: log the value of startDate in the this.startDate functions parameter 
```
setStartDate = startDate => {
console.log(this.state.startDate)
        this.setState({
            startDate: startDate
        });
        
      };
``` 
and see if you accessing the corrrect value